# Defining a route for a method in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I'm new to Rails and currently using Rails 3, so please bear with me. I have a basic app, with a basic scaffolded controller/model e.g Contacts.

Amongst the methods for Show/Edit etc.. i have added a method called newcontacts (i have also added a newcontacts.html.erb), which will eventually show the last 5 contacts imported , but at the moment i am using the same code one would find in the basic Index method of a controller (i intend to filter the data at a later point), the method in the controller is -

```
def newcontacts

  @contacts = Contact.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
  end
end
```

I can access localhost:3000/contacts which displays the index method action from the contact controller, but when i try and access this method (newcontacts) using localhost:3000/contacts/newcontacts it returns the error

```
Couldn't find Contact with id=newcontacts
```

I have looked at the routes.rb file as i believe this is what needs editing, and have added the following line to routes.rb

```
match 'newcontacts', :to => 'contacts#newcontacts'
```

but this only works when i call localhost:3000/newcontacts.

So my question is, how do i get the url localhost:3000/contacts/newcontacts to work?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to do is [add another RESTful action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

```
resources :contacts do
  # This will map to /contacts/newcontacts
  get 'newcontacts', :on => :collection # Or (not and; use only one of these)...

  # This will map to /contacts/:id/newcontacts
  get 'newcontacts', :on => :member     # ... if you want to pass in a contact id.
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When i go to /contacts/newcontacts it now displays `No route matches [GET] "/contacts/newcontacts"`

Comment: @AndyN Did you remove the other `match` route? Is there a `link_to` or something in the template?

Comment: Is match 'newcontacts', :to => 'contacts#newcontacts' still required?  I am currently getting the error config/routes.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end (SyntaxError) with it in?

Comment: @AndyN No, it needs to be removed. I left out the `do` in my example--it was shown in the link I provided; did you review that?

Comment: Thats it! I'd copy and pasted the do out, many thanks for your help, all working as required now. Cheers

Comment: @AndyN No sweat--syntax can be a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your routes.rb file:

```
resources :contacts do
  member do
    put 'newcontacts'
  end
end
```

That will add in a new action for the contacts controller.

Comment: That would actually be `/contacts/:id/newcontacts`. That may be what's desired; I wasn't sure.

Comment: Yes - now I've seen what you've answered I suspect you've grasped the requirement better than me :)